# Need Help Implementing An If/Else Or Case Statement Into Python Script

Tags: python, json, csv, web-crawler

The code crawls the website and then prints out internal and external links and stores it into a txt, json, xml, and csv file.
Need help with implementing an if/else or case statement where I can choose which file format I can have the results (internal and external links) in.
Also, need help making this more optimize or better than it currently is if possible.
How to execute program: python filename url
My Output:
Total Internal Links: ....
Total External Links: ....
Total Links: ...
Then exports those links to a txt, son, csv, and XML file.

```
import requests
import argparse
import time
import json
import random
import pandas as pd
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

internal_links = set()
external_links = set()
urls = []
total_links_visited = 0

#check if url is valid
def is_valid(url):
   parsed = urlparse(url)
   return bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)

#this function finds and prints out the internal and external links
def get_all_website_links(url):
   global urls
   domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
   res1 = requests.get(url)
   soup = BeautifulSoup(res1.content, "html.parser")
   for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
      href_tag = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
      if href_tag:
         href_tag = urljoin(url, href_tag)
         parsed_href = urlparse(href_tag)
         href_tag = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
         if is_valid(href_tag):
            if domain_name not in urlparse(href_tag).netloc and href_tag not in external_links:
               print(f"External link: {href_tag}")
               external_links.add(href_tag)
               continue
            elif href_tag not in urls:
               print(f"Internal link: {href_tag}")
               urls.append(href_tag)
               internal_links.add(href_tag)

#this function crawls a web page and extracts all links
def crawl(url, max_urls=50):
   global total_links_visited, urls
   total_links_visited += 1
   get_all_website_links(url)
   for link in urls:
      if total_links_visited > max_urls:
         break
      crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)

#main function
def main():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Link Extractor Tool with Python")
   parser.add_argument("url", help="The URL to extract links from.")
   parser.add_argument("-m", "--max-urls", help="Number of max URLs to crawl, default is 30.", default=30, type=int)
   args = parser.parse_args()
   url = args.url
   max_urls = args.max_urls
   domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
   res = requests.get(url)
   statuscode = res.status_code
   print("Status Code:", statuscode)
   if statuscode == 200: 
      crawl(url, max_urls=max_urls)
   else:
      print("Failed to get a request response back.")

   print("Total Internal Links:", len(internal_links))
   print("Total External Links:", len(external_links))
   print("Total Links:", len(external_links) + len(internal_links))
    
   with open(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.txt", "w") as f:
      for internal_link in internal_links:
         print(internal_link.strip(), file=f)
   with open(f"{domain_name}_external_links.txt", "w") as f:
      for external_link in external_links:
         print(external_link.strip(), file=f)

   #writing to json files
   f = open(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.json","w")
   json.dump({'internal_links':list(internal_links)}, f, indent=6)
   f.close()
   f = open(f"{domain_name}_external_links.json","w")
   json.dump({'external_links':list(external_links)}, f, indent=6)
   f.close()

   #writing to csv
   df = pd.DataFrame(list(internal_links))
   df.to_csv(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.csv", index=False, header=False)
   df = pd.DataFrame(list(external_links))
   df.to_csv(f"{domain_name}_external_links.csv", index=False, header=False)

   #writing to xml
   xmlformat = xml.Element("internal_links")
   xmlformat_1 = xml.SubElement(xmlformat, "link")
   for l in list(internal_links):
      xmlformat_1.text = str(l)
      xmlformat.append(xmlformat_1)
   tree = xml.ElementTree(xmlformat)
   tree.write(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.xml")

   xmlformat = xml.Element("external_links")
   xmlformat_1 = xml.SubElement(xmlformat, "link")
   for l in list(external_links):
      xmlformat_1.text = str(l)
      xmlformat.append(xmlformat_1)
   tree = xml.ElementTree(xmlformat)
   tree.write(f"{domain_name}_external_links.xml")

#executing the python script
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: You can add one more command line argument for file format

Answer (score 0):

You can one more command line argument called `output-file-format`

```
import requests
import argparse
import time
import json
import random
import pandas as pd
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml
from urllib.request import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

internal_links = set()
external_links = set()
urls = []
total_links_visited = 0

#check if url is valid
def is_valid(url):
   parsed = urlparse(url)
   return bool(parsed.netloc) and bool(parsed.scheme)

#this function finds and prints out the internal and external links
def get_all_website_links(url):
    global urls
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    res1 = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res1.content, "html.parser")
    for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
        href_tag = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href_tag:
            href_tag = urljoin(url, href_tag)
            parsed_href = urlparse(href_tag)
            href_tag = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
            if is_valid(href_tag):
                if domain_name not in urlparse(href_tag).netloc and href_tag not in external_links:
                    print(f"External link: {href_tag}")
                    external_links.add(href_tag)
                    continue
                elif href_tag not in urls:
                    print(f"Internal link: {href_tag}")
                    urls.append(href_tag)
                    internal_links.add(href_tag)

#this function crawls a web page and extracts all links
def crawl(url, max_urls=50):
    global total_links_visited, urls
    total_links_visited += 1
    get_all_website_links(url)
    for link in urls:
        if total_links_visited > max_urls:
            break
        crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)

def save(output_file_format, domain_name, internal_links, external_links):
    if output_file_format == "json":
        #writing to json files
        f = open(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.json","w")
        json.dump({'internal_links':list(internal_links)}, f, indent=6)
        f.close()
        f = open(f"{domain_name}_external_links.json","w")
        json.dump({'external_links':list(external_links)}, f, indent=6)
        f.close()

    elif output_file_format == "csv":
        #writing to csv
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(internal_links))
        df.to_csv(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.csv", index=False, header=False)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(external_links))
        df.to_csv(f"{domain_name}_external_links.csv", index=False, header=False)

    elif output_file_format == "xml":
        #writing to xml
        xmlformat = xml.Element("internal_links")
        xmlformat_1 = xml.SubElement(xmlformat, "link")
        for l in list(internal_links):
            xmlformat_1.text = str(l)
            xmlformat.append(xmlformat_1)
        tree = xml.ElementTree(xmlformat)
        tree.write(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.xml")

        xmlformat = xml.Element("external_links")
        xmlformat_1 = xml.SubElement(xmlformat, "link")
        for l in list(external_links):
            xmlformat_1.text = str(l)
            xmlformat.append(xmlformat_1)
        tree = xml.ElementTree(xmlformat)
        tree.write(f"{domain_name}_external_links.xml")
    else:
        with open(f"{domain_name}_internal_links.txt", "w") as f:
            for internal_link in internal_links:
                print(internal_link.strip(), file=f)
        with open(f"{domain_name}_external_links.txt", "w") as f:
            for external_link in external_links:
                print(external_link.strip(), file=f)

#main function
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Link Extractor Tool with Python")
    parser.add_argument("url", help="The URL to extract links from.")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--max-urls", help="Number of max URLs to crawl, default is 30.", default=30, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--output-file-format", help="Output file format to store the data. Default text", default="txt")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    url = args.url
    max_urls = args.max_urls
    output_file_format = args.output_file_format
    domain_name = urlparse(url).netloc
    res = requests.get(url)
    statuscode = res.status_code
    print("Status Code:", statuscode)
    if statuscode == 200: 
        crawl(url, max_urls=max_urls)
    else:
        print("Failed to get a request response back.")

    print("Total Internal Links:", len(internal_links))
    print("Total External Links:", len(external_links))
    print("Total Links:", len(external_links) + len(internal_links))

    save(output_file_format, domain_name, internal_links, external_links)
   

#executing the python script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Usage:

```
usage: a.py [-h] [-m MAX_URLS] [-t OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT] url
a.py: error: the following arguments are required: url
```

Running the file:

```
python pyfile3.py -m 1 -t csv https://www.youtube.com
```

Output:

```
Status Code: 200
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/press/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/copyright/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/creators/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/ads/
External link: https://developers.google.com/youtube
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/t/terms
External link: https://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/policies/privacy/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/policies/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/new
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/experiences/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/about/brand-resources/
External link: https://youtube.googleblog.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/trends/
External link: https://twitter.com/YouTube
External link: https://www.instagram.com/youtube/
External link: https://www.facebook.com/youtube/
Internal link: https://youtube.googleblog.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/jobs/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/howyoutubeworks/
External link: https://www.youtubego.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/kids/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/musicpremium
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCqVDpXKLmKeBU_yyt_QkItQ
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/premium/
External link: https://studio.youtube.com/
External link: https://tv.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/
External link: https://artists.youtube.com/
External link: https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/page/education
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/yt/family/
External link: https://youtube.com/creatorresearch/
External link: https://servicesdirectory.withyoutube.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/nextup
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/space/
External link: https://vr.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com/creators-for-change/
External link: https://youtube.com/csai-match/
External link: https://socialimpact.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtubego.com/
Internal link: https://studio.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://tv.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://artists.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/page/education
Internal link: https://youtube.com/creatorresearch/
Internal link: https://servicesdirectory.withyoutube.com/
Internal link: https://vr.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://youtube.com/csai-match/
Internal link: https://socialimpact.youtube.com/
Internal link: https://www.youtube.com
External link: https://www.google.com/policies/privacy/
External link: https://support.google.com/youtube/
Total Internal Links: 36
Total External Links: 18
Total Links: 54
```

Comment: I get an error when using python filename.py url csv/xml/json.
I get the same error as you. Any ideas? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: You need to give the command line arguments while running the program. https://medium.com/code-85/how-to-pass-command-line-values-to-a-python-script-1e3e7b244c89

Comment: C:\Users\slee5\Desktop\Crawler>python pyfile3.py https://www.youtube.com/ csv
usage: pyfile3.py [-h] [-m MAX_URLS] [-t OUTPUT_FILE_FORMAT] url
pyfile3.py: error: unrecognized arguments: csv

Comment: @SamLee `python pyfile3.py -m 1 -t csv https://www.youtube.com`. You need to give at the end

Comment: @SamLee Updated my answer. Upvote and accept if it has solved your question

Comment: Quick question, how can I do this command instead: python pyfile3.py csv https://www.youtube.com?
Looks great!

Comment: @SamLee Can you explain more by "how can I do this"?

Comment: Sorry, how can I make this command line possible:  python pyfile3.py csv youtube.com
Instead of python pyfile3.py -m 1 -t csv https://www.youtube.com

Comment: Is the t necessary, assuming it is? Is there a way not to add that t?

Comment: @SamLee you can change the default to csv, I have given as text file. Change `default="txt"` to `default="csv"`

Comment: What's the t for? I am fine with the default as txt. Just want my command line argument to be: python filename.py csv https://www.youtube.com

Comment: Because you are using argparse in your code, you will have to give it explicitly

Comment: Aight cool. Solves my original question. Thanks a ton! Much appreciate the quick response. I might ask a different question but same code later on.

Comment: @SamLee Upvote and accept the answer if it has solved your question

Comment: @SamLee https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/645086